# How to upload my own wordpress theme to my blog xxx.wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress, upload, wordpress-theming

Do you know how can I upload my own wordpress theme to my blog in xxx.wordpress.com ?

I have buy a new domain name.

need help pleas

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload your own theme. You can point a domain at wordpress.com. See [The difference between WordPress.com, WordPress, and WordPress.org](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/)